# A #define in C with three dots

Tags: c, label, c-preprocessor, notation, variadic-macros

```
#define LOGI(...) ((void)__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "native-activity", __VA_ARGS__))
#define LOGW(...) ((void)__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_WARN, "native-activity", __VA_ARGS__))
```

This is definition for these 2 macros; later in the code `LOGI` and `LOGW` are used this way

```
LOGI("accelerometer: x=%f y=%f z=%f",
                                event.acceleration.x, event.acceleration.y,
                                event.acceleration.z);
```

and this way

```
LOGW("Unable to eglMakeCurrent");
```

Since I try to avoid complex macros and `#define` in general, I can't get what this macro actually means.  What is the role for the 3 dots notation here? What does this `#define` change later in the code?

Obviously I know that the 3 dots are used to indicate and indefinite amount of arguments, but I don't know how to read this situation.

Comment: It's called a variadic macro. http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html

Comment: @chris so it's a way for trying to be less verbose and rearrange the arguments in a certain way?

Comment: Hmm, I would have used `##__VA_ARGS__`, but I guess it's OK as long as you have to give an argument.

Comment: @Ken: A variadic macro lets the macro take an arbitrary number of arguments (similar in spirit to the `printf` function). That way, you can give a macro a format string and arguments to the format string. It is, as you see here, most commonly used to wrap variadic functions.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The C99 standard introduced *variadic macros*, i.e., function-like macros that can take a variable number of arguments.

Quoting the [latest draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) of the C standard, section 6.10.3:

> If the identifier-list in the macro definition does not end with an
>   ellipsis, the number of arguments (including those arguments
>   consisting of no preprocessing tokens) in an invocation of a
>   function-like macro shall equal the number of parameters in the macro
>   definition. Otherwise, there shall be more arguments in the invocation
>   than there are parameters in the macro definition (excluding the `...`).
>   There shall exist a ) preprocessing token that terminates the
>   invocation.
>
> The identifier `__VA_ARGS__` shall occur only in the replacement-list of
>   a function-like macro that uses the ellipsis notation in the
>   parameters.

...

> If there is a `...` in the identifier-list in the macro definition,
>   then the trailing arguments, including any separating comma
>   preprocessing tokens, are merged to form a single item: the *variable
>   arguments*. The  number of arguments so combined is such that,
>   following merger, the number of arguments is one more than the number
>   of parameters in the macro definition (excluding the `...`).

And in the next subsection:

> An identifier `__VA_ARGS__` that occurs in the replacement list shall
>   be treated as if it were a parameter, and the variable arguments shall
>   form the preprocessing tokens used to replace it.

So you can invoke `LOGI` or `LOGW` with as many arguments as you like, and they'll all be expanded at the place specified in the definition by the reference to `__VA_ARGS__`.

Comment: By the way, is `##__VA_ARGS__` (commonly used to handle the case of zero arguments provided to a variadic macro) allowed by the standard? Is it even necessary?

Comment: The `##__VA_ARGS__` notation is a GCC extension.

Comment: Yes, it is an extension, and can be replaced by other techniques that count the number of arguments that the macro receives.